# android implementing 47deg SwipeListView with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe-gesture, swiperefreshlayout

I am using 47deg SwipeListView library.
I have to add to my list view the SwipeRefreshLayout feature.
both are working but now after implementing the swipe to refresh method, 
if I swipe the last view to the left, and my finger goes a little bit down.. the left swipe animation is getting stuck and the pull to the refresh method is starting to show.

anyway to lock the SwipeRefreshLayout while using swipe gestures?

Thanks.